# How to rename multiple files in a manner of A_B_C into B_A_C?

Tags: renaming

In the Mount & Blade: Warband video game, I'm mixing textures from two modules (the native game and a mod). The problem here is that the textures are named differently in both modules, and I don't want to change `.txt` files for what filenames to load. I'm totally green in programming, to help myself I've so far learned super basic renaming via `.bat` files.

A situation I stumbled upon are multiple files named in a manner like

`armor_TEXT1_TEXT2.dds` in the mod

`TEXT1_armor_TEXT2.dds` in native

How can I quickly rename all files from the mod to the way they're named in native? Thank you.

Comment: There are various multi-rename or bulk-rename tools with support for rearranging file name parts. In specific cases (including your example) it could also be done using a batchfile like shown here: https://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-file-rename-reorder-filename-parts/21309.html

Comment: This seems simpler than @Jsleshem 's way, I'll try to work it out tomorrow. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Open your favorite shell, and move the files. The example I am giving is what I would do in my bash shell:

Locate the files

Navigate to that directory in your (possibly bash) shell

Once you are in the proper directory, make sure you can R/W/E to both files (If you cannot, run the command `ls -ltra` to see what permissions you have default. Then, use `chmod` to change what you need to change)

Finally, type `mv armor_TEXT1_TEXT2.dds TEXT1_armor_TEXT2.dds`

*NOTES

Before doing any of this, make sure to save backups to prevent any errors that are irreparable.

The commands I used may not have the same syntax in your shell. If that is the case, look online to find the differences between your shell and a bash shell.